# Change labels on a WMS-map with premade labels

Tags: qgis

I got a WMS-map of Norway.
It already has place names, but I only want my own to be shown.
How do I remove the place names thats already on the map?

Answer (score 0):

A WMS provides a picture of some map data. There is generally no way to remove elements from that map.

It is possible that the server operator allows you to provide your own style sheet (SLD) as discussed in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112349/using-sld-with-wms?rq=1) but I don't think QGis has provision for this. The only option would be to down load the data and serve it yourself with your modifications to the style.